# Can't get Laravel to work with apache on Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, laravel, vhosts

I've been trying for serveral hours to get Laravel to work with Apache running Ubuntu 14.04 to no result. I'm trying to get the Laravel welcome page show if I go to site.dev but instead it only shows me the default apache page that it shows if I go to localhost. It seems to only show the welcome page if I go to localhost/laravel/public. I have the laravel folder in the /var/www/html/ directory which seems to be the document root on apache on Ubuntu (I only ever used WAMP on Windows before). I followed instructions for making a virtual host file for Laravel, which is at:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf
```

And its contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName site.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel/public
</VirtualHost>
```

I then ran this to enable it:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/laravel.conf
service apache2 reload
```

This is also how my /etc/hosts file look like now:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   which1ispink-EP31-DS3L
127.0.0.1   site.dev

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Did you enable rewrite? sudo a2en rewrite

Comment: Yes I did. Though I think the command was "sudo a2enmod rewrite". "sudo a2en rewrite" shows command not found.

Comment: That's it.  Forgot the syntax.

Comment: I think you need to specifically allow rewriting for your vhost.

Comment: add AllowOverride All  after ServerName site.dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you ran basically just allows apache to use mod rewrite. You need to specifically turn it on for your vhost. Adding a `<directory>` section with `AllowOverride all` should get it working.